# How to convert the dataframe column type from string to (array and struct) in spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with the following schema, where 'name' is a string type and the value
is a complex JSON with Array and struct.

Basically with string datatype i couldn't able to parse the data and write into rows.
So I am trying to convert datatype and apply explode to parse the data.

```
Current:
root
|--id: string (nullable = true)
|--partitionNo: string (nullable = true)
|--name: string (nullable = true)
```

After conversion:

```
Expected:
root
|id: string (nullable = true)
|partitionNo: string (nullable = true)
|name: array (nullable = true)
|     |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
|     |    |-- extension: array (nullable = true)
|     |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|     |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
|     |    |    |    |-- valueMetadata: struct (nullable = true)
|     |    |    |    |-- modifiedDateTime: string (nullable = true)
|     |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
|     |    |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
|     |    |-- firstName: array (nullable = true)
|     |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `from_json`, but you need to provide a schema, which can be automatically inferred using a spaghetti code... because `from_json` only accepts a schema in the form of `lit`:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "name",
    from_json(
        $"name",
        // the lines below generate the schema
        lit(
            df.select(
                schema_of_json(
                    lit(
                        df.select($"name").head()(0)
                    )
                )
            ).head()(0)
        )
        // end of schema generation
    )
)
```

Comment: I think from_json could support a schema as DataType.

Comment: @timothyzhang yes, but I don't want to type it manually for a complex schema...